# hosted build controller with custom binaries

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

I have .NET 4.5 project that I am hosting in Visual Studio Online. It uses binaries from Dynamics CRM SDK (microsoft.xrm.sdk.dll and microsoft.xrm.client.dll. When I schedule a build it fails with error that microsoft.xrm.sdk.dll and microsoft.xrm.client.dll not found.

I followed steps at the bottom of this page to add those assembiles to a folder and added that to the srouce code.  http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/hosted-build-controller-vs.aspx

Also updated hosted build controller to make sure it has the path set to custom binaries. But I continue to get same error. Any idea what might be wrong? Thanks,

D

Answer (score 0):

The location you edited on the build location called "Version control path to custom assemblies" is the location to the assemblies used by your build process template, not MSBuild.

If you have a project with a reference to the Dynamic's SDK it will probably look something like this:

```
<Reference Include="microsoft.xrm.sdk.dll" />
```

It might have the Full Assembly Name with version, public key etc.

This will be resolving the reference from the GAC more than likely, because you cannot install things on a hosted build agent, you will need to provide a hint path to the SDK. This probably means checking in the SDK DLL's into source control and then updating the reference from your project(s) to point to them:

```
<Reference Include="microsoft.xrm.sdk.dll ">
  <HintPath>..\..\3rd Party\microsoft.xrm.sdk.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

If that doesn't appeal to you, you could look at using the NuGet [Packages for Dynamics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2014/02/12/dynamics-crm-2011-and-2013-sdk-assemblies-now-on-nuget.aspx) and using package restore to (or check in the packages).